# Number N denoting the length of the inputted array

Tags: python, arrays

**While solving some progrmaming problems, I've noticed that the dialogue says:**

> Input:
>
> Integer N denoting size of array
>
> Next line contains N space separated integers denoting elements in
>   array

How am I supposed to use the variable N so that it is functioning as supposed to and not just a useless-floating-around input-variable...

I mean, it could just be one input denoting the elements of the array, no need for the length of its elements...

PS: I know that I can just add it there just to pass the problem, I am just asking about if that N variable could be useful using Python (Without the way of a for loop, to ask N number of times for input cause it won't pass the problem).

Comment: You can take that first input and use it to create a for loop to go through the following numbers and add them to a list.

Comment: The input in itself is redundant and can be incorrect ("2" and "1 2 3"). I don't think any programming language can change that fact.

Comment: The problem may be prompting you to try to do this on your own, without split(). In this case, you could use a for loop and a while loop to find each individual space. In general however, I would not recommend this approach for the same reasons you gave

Comment: Generic programming problems like this often have the sizes in the input to make it easier to implement them in languages that require you to declare the size of arrays, like C. It's redundant in a language like Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python it usually is, since usually you fetch the entire line at once and process it.

Some programming languages like C++ and Java however tend to benefit from this approach since some parser tools (like Java's `Scanner`) work by parsing one integer at a time.

You can simply parse your input like:

```
input() # ignore the 'N'
arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=list(map(int,input().split())
print(x)
```

Try this 
you will get an array of integers

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want space-separated numbers with the length defined as the input. You can achieve that by:

```
N = input("Integer N denoting size of array: ")
print(" ".join(str(i + 1) for i in range(int(N))))
```

e.g.:

```
Integer N denoting size of array: 12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```